# Estimating compressed file size using a list parameter

Tags: linux, compression, tar, perl

I am currently compressing a list of files from a directory in the following format:

> tar -cvjf test_1.tar.gz -T test_1.lst --no-recursion

The above command will compress only those files mentioned in the list. I am doing this because this list is generated such that it fits a DVD. However, during compression the compression rate decreases the estimated file size and there is abundant space left in the DVD. This is something like a Knapsack algorithm.

I would like to estimate the compressed file size and add some more files to the list. I found that it is possible to estimate file size using the following command:

> tar -cjf - Folder/ | wc -c

This command does not take a list parameter. Is there a way to estimate compressed file size? I am also looking into options like perl scripts etc.

**Edit:**

I think I should provide more information since I have been doing a lot of web search. I came across a perl script([Link](https://github.com/sabujp/splitTars/blob/master/splitTars))that sort of emulates the Knapsack algorithm.

The current problem with the above mentioned script is that it splits the files in their original state. When I compress the files after splitting them, there are opportunities for adding more files which I consider to be inefficient.

There are 2 ways I could resolve the inefficiency:

a) Compress individual files and save them in a directory using a script. The compressed file could provide a best estimate. I could generate a script using a folder of compressed files and use them on the uncompressed ones.

b) Check whether the compressed file's size is less than the required size. If so, I should keep adding files until I meet the requirement. However, the addition of new files to the compressed file is an optimization problem by itself.

Answer (score 1):

#### Edit 2:

I re-read your question, and found a new way to interpret it. It is simple to find the size of a file after compression, using something like `bzip2 -k $file | wc -c` on every file. This, however will not solve your problem, as you are not interested in the size of each compressed file, but the compressed size of a tarball containing all your files (and how much it increases if you add a specific file). The size difference from compression is not [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity) but in fact rather unpredictable, so the one is a poor predictor for the second.

An example is two identical files of 10 MiB, where both compress individually to 1 MiB and a tarball containing both also compresses to 1 MiB.

#### Original answer

I believe the common solution if to just split the compressed data with [`split`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?split), which means you need all the resulting disks available if you want to recover a file from any of them. I think `tar` has a built-in splitting mechanism, but it only works on the amount of uncompressed data, which gives poor results with compression and non-homogenous files.

A different solution (far from perfect) works if you can have manual intervention and might be sufficient. It works best if your files are large compared to the desired volume size

I take you have a target volume size, in MiB. In the example, I use 700 MiB.

If you run

```
tout="/tmp/09b00c50a9625deeb1089b3c4358c5e5" #or something else
csize="7" # in MiB
mkfifo "$tout"
tar -cvj ~/ 2>"$tout" | dd bs=1M count="$csize" of=/dev/null iflag=fullblock 2>/dev/null &
tail -20 "$tout" | xargs -n 1 ls -ld
rm "$tout"
```

`tar` will print out all the files it tries to compress to the pipe, until dd has received 700 MiB of compressed data. `tail` reads the last 20 files that `tar` attempted to compress from the fifo.

The last file printed (at least) won't be able to fit within your volume size. Due to caching in both `tar` and `bzip2`, several of the other last files might not fit either, though, so you might have to experiment a bit with how many of them you skip. If all the files are very small you might have to tell `tail` to print out more than 20 of them to see the one that turns you over the limit.

#### Edit:

You could even write the filenames to your file list directly (with a suitable filter to remove directories) and just delete the last few lines in a text editor.

Comment: I have provided some more information in my edit to the post. I am looking forward to hear your thoughts on the same